# FoundationDB as storage backend for JanusGraph: still feasible and advisable?

Tags: janusgraph, foundationdb

I'm interested to know the state of the *JanusGraph-FoundationDB Storage Adapter*:

Four years ago it was announced: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQM_ZPZy8Ck&list=PLU8TPe7k8z9ew5W6YpACnGvjBDYaJVORZ&index=1

According to the README: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-foundationdb, the storage adapter is compatible only for the *JanusGraph version 0.5.2* with *FoundationDB version 6.2.22*, while the latest JanusGraph version is 0.6.3 and the latest FoundationDB version is 7.2 (https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/).

Since I don't see FoundationDB listed in storage backends

[image]

and there is no official JanusGraph documentation about FoundationDB as backend storage, I would like to know if it is still feasible, and, more importantly, advisable, to use FoundationDB as storage backend for JanusGraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Foundation DB is not officially supported with Janusgraph, but based on my research I found that ScyllaDB is more performant with Janusgraph. If you want to use the latest version of Janusgraph then you may end up with compatibility issues with Foundation DB